# Category theory book with lots of examples

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

A student of mine is writing her Bachelor's thesis in which she has to use several categorical concepts (co/equalizers, co/products, subobjects, (regular) monomorphisms, etc.) in a couple of different categories (at least in the category $CMon$ of commutative monoids and in $SLatt_0$, the category of sup-semilattices with $0$). Instead of introducing these notions several times, she has decided to introduce the general notions in an abstract category and then prove that they take the form she needs in $CMon$ and in $SLatt_0$. On the other hand, now that she has these definitions, it would be nice to include examples about these constructions in other categories she knows (e.g., groups, monoids, sets, abelian groups, etc.) but, as she will not use these examples and as the draft is already long enough at this point, it would be better to avoid proofs for all these examples and just cite some references.

Hence, my question is: Can anyone suggest some reference where co/equalizers, co/products, subobjects, and similar notions are fully described, possibly with at least a hint of an argument, in several examples of commonly used categories (possibly, at least in sets, monoids, groups and abelian groups)?

Comment: Section IV.2 of Mac Lane's "Categories for the Working Mathematician" has a wonderful table of explicit, familiar examples of adjunctions and their unit and counit maps. Unfortunately the specific notions you asked for (co/equalizers, co/products, etc.) aren't given explicitly there, but since right adjoints preserve limits and left adjoints preserve colimits, you can infer (without much trouble) what many of those notions have to be in the given examples. This isn't quite what you asked for, so it's a comment, not an answer. Sorry if this doesn't wind up being helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that is actually an elegant solution for this problem. On the other hand, my student did not include adjoint functors in her thesis. The thesis was not meant to be about category theory, her assignment was to prove a version of Isbell's ZigZag Theorem, describing epimorphisms, for the category of commutative monoids, so she is working inside a given category and just exploiting some universal constructions. I am afraid that introducing her to adjoint functors with the short time she has to finish could be confusing for her.

Comment: Lawvere & Schanuel?

Comment: Emily Riehl's book _Category theory in context_ is worth a look, though it's not exactly what you want.

Comment: Adámek-Herrlich's "Abstract and concrete categories" is full of examples for every abstract concept they introduce.

Comment: Using the comment section to give answers again? ;)

Comment: Mac Lane's book is still a great source of elementary examples even before the introduction of Adjoint Functors. Actually she might just gather all the examples of universal constructions she met along her graduation studies, and then order and describe them from a categorical viewpoint.  However, even if time is short, I would kindly force her to study adjunctions too. Maybe try writing her an anonymous  blackmail letter!

Comment: No one mentioned Borceux's Handbook! The chapter on limits has many examples in categories of interest. There's also Awodey's book, with very explicit mentions of pushouts in Set (and with a little bit of effort, in many other categories), from which one can easily define coequalisers.

Comment: Herrlich and Strecker is, accordi g to  my recollection, exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @PietroMajer I know, actually I have briefly discussed adjoint functors with her, underlying their importance in describing monomorphism in several concrete categories. The main application was the fact that, given a concrete category like Ab, CMon, Grp, Mon, etc. that have (finite) products and equalizers, and where the forgetful functor is a right adjoint (to the "free object functor") we have that monomorphism=injective morphism. Still, she is just starting with Cats and she feels more comfortable with direct (low-level) arguments. This will certainly change given enough time :-)

Comment: Thank you Steven and Fosco, I think that Borceux and Herrlich-Strecker will do the job!

Comment: There is also _Einführung in die Kategorientheorie_ by Martin Brandenburg, which also has a lot of examples.

Comment: @SimoneVirili --of course, I was joking and didn't mean to bully the poor student :)

Comment: Not all books have examples for everything. How about making this question community wiki and each answer contains a reference which has many examples for one notion?